# Значение переменной не соответствует ожидаемому

Tags: c

Здравствуйте!
В упор не могу понять, почему значение переменной `s` не соответствует ожидаемому?

```
#include <stdio.h>              
#include <locale.h>
#include <math.h>

int main(void)

{
    signed int a1, a2, b1, b2, c1, c2;
    double s;

    //получаем значения переменных из stdin

    s = 0.5 * ((a1 - c1)*(b2 - c2) - (b1 - c1)*(a2 - c2));
    if (s = 0.0) {
        //это условие никогда не выполняется — почему?
    }

    // дальше какой-то код

    return 0;
}
```

Спасибо.

Comment: Что значит мусор? Вещественные типы так не сравнивают. Тем более у тебя даже не сравнение (==), а присваивание.

Comment: @АнтонСазонов, нашёл ошибку, спасибо. забыл.

Comment: В будущем, пожалуйста, указывайте точно: ожидал ______, получил ______. Выражение «мусор в переменную» абсолютно непонятно, оттого и минусы.

Comment: @NickVolynkin, Хорошо, учту, спасибо. Минусы как-то переживу.

Comment: Кстати, а в чем смысл умножать число на `0,5`, если мы его потом только сравниваем с нулем?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

У Вас стандартная ошибка с присваиванием вместо сравнения

```
if (s = 0.0) {...}
```

а должно быть

```
if (s == 0.0) {...}
```

и как уже справедливо заметили, сравнивать вещественные так действительно нельзя

Comment: Вообще, нельзя, но в данном случае можно. Оно вообще половина целого.

Answer (score 8):

Если хочешь сравнить с нулём, делай так:

```
if ( fabs( s ) <= eps ) ...
```

, где **eps** - какое-то очень маленькое число, точность сравнения.

Answer (score 7):

Застраховать себя от таких ошибок чтобы, [Условия Йоды](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A3%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%8F_%D0%99%D0%BE%D0%B4%D1%8B) использовать должны вы:

```
if (0 == s) ...
```

Числа с плавающей точкой сравнивать чтобы, [используй эпсилон](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/451065/181472), молодой джедай.